# QString.toInt() doesnt work - Error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const char *' and 'const char [14]')

Tags: qt, type-conversion, qt5, qstring

I have this code:

```
QString carda = "000123";
QString queryStringAnet("SELECT * FROM [records] WHERE ([user]='" + carda.toInt() + "' AND [apl]='"+apl+"' AND [tasktype]='"+taskType+"' AND [taskkind]='"+taskKind+"' AND [timestamp]='"+timestamp+"')");
```

and for the conversion from QString to Int when I use carda.toInt() Im having this error:

> error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const char *' and
>   'const char [14]')

and warnings:

```
warning: adding 'int' to a string does not append to the string
use array indexing to silence this warning
```

I dont understand why QString.toInt() wont be working... any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I dont understand why QString.toInt() wont be working... any idea?

the problem is that in qt you just can't concatenate together strings and numbers...

and actually you dont even need to convert the string ***carda*** to integer because that is a QString

instead just do:

```
QString queryStringAnet("SELECT * FROM [records] WHERE ([user]='" + carda + "' AND [apl]='"+apl+"' AND [tasktype]='"+taskType+"' AND [taskkind]='"+taskKind+"' AND [timestamp]='"+timestamp+"')");
```

Comment: this isn't even Qt, this is C/C++, adding string literals (char*) and an int won't work.

Comment: thanks for the comment bro... but trust me, qt has many ways to concatenate weird things... and QStrings are very diff to std::strings ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Au contraire! ;-) _qt has many ways to concatenate weird things_ Even Qt cannot (and should not) overload the binary add operator for `const char*` and `int`. (In OPs exposed code, the term with C string literal and `int` is given as argument to the constructor of `QString` - no `QString` involved in `+`.)